# The mouse pointer in my Ubuntu VM has turned into a little hand with a document, and clicks are ignored. How do I get out of this mode?

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, cursor, mouse-click

The mouse pointer in my Ubuntu 8.04.3 LTS VM (running in VMware Fusion) has changed into a little hand holding a document.  It doesn't show up in screen-shots.

All mouse clicks (left or right) are ignored.  But I can still type in the one Terminal window I have open.  (And commands work fine.)

I wonder if I'm in some kind of drag-and-drop mode.

How do I get out of this?

**Update:** [Rebooting (from the command-line)](https://superuser.com/questions/81005/how-do-i-restart-linux-ubuntu-from-the-command-line) worked.  Ubuntu came up with the regular mouse-pointer.

Comment: Hey Daryl. If that command-line reboot has fixed the problem, you may want to add your fix as an answer to your own question, then accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I've found is to [reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/81005/how-do-i-restart-linux-ubuntu-from-the-command-line).

Answer (score 2):

I solved it (without having to reboot) by [performing these steps](http://www.eatmybusiness.com/food/2011/10/18/how-to-get-rid-of-cursor-stuck-as-drag-n-drop-icon-on-vmware-player-document-with-hand/195/). Which was basically dragging some text from the host to the guest machine.

I think I had the same problem as what you have - can't be sure though. Try it anyway.

Comment: Clicking on the URL gives: `Error. Page cannot be displayed. Please contact your service provider for more details. (26)`

Answer (score 1):

Switching to a VT via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> or the like, logging in, and then killing the app via `kill` will release the lock on the pointer.

Comment: After doing this, you can use Ctrl+Alt+F7 to get back to the GUI

Answer (score 1):

If you do Ctrl + Alt + F1 followed by Ctrl + Alt + F7, this may fix the problem.

Comment: Why? Can you elaborate on what this does? (it should switch to a `tty` and back to `X`, but why does that help?)

Comment: I think it's because it stops drawing the pointer, and when you return to GUI, it must redraw it

Answer (score 0):

Just logging out (Ctrl+Alt+Del) solved the issue for me