# How do I restart Linux (Ubuntu) from the command-line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, reboot

Because of m[y problem with mouse-clicks being ignored in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/81003/the-mouse-pointer-in-my-ubuntu-vm-has-turned-into-a-little-hand-with-a-document), I want to restart from the command-line.  (I have an open Terminal, and the keyboard is not ignored.)

How do I restart a computer running Linux (or more specifically Ubuntu) from the command-line?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There's a few ways:

```
sudo reboot
```

```
sudo init 6
```

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Be careful with init. If the inittab has been changed, init 6 may be mapped to some other runlevel. I've seen a number of places that had the default runlevel after reboot set to single-user mode.

Comment: What about if you're not `sudo`? When *clicking*, you don't have to be `sudo`...

Answer (score 9):

If you've got freedesktop-compliant session manager, you can use DBus to invoke restart from inside the X session. The command goes:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal --type=method_call \
    --print-reply /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
    org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Reboot int32:0
```

(this is probably more than necessary; works for me). I use this in a shell script. You don't need to run this from `root`, but you need to run it from inside an X session (f.e. in a terminal). You can find more on this topic at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingGNOMEPowerManager

Comment: What is the advantage of this over `sudo reboot`?

Comment: It will notify your session manager that you're about to reboot, and f.e. save your session status (apps opened). I'm not sure whether `reboot` or `shutdown` does that. Also, as I wrote in the answer, you don't need sudo or su (you need to be allowed to do that by session manager, but this is usually true in most desktop distros).

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally, the usual (and preferred) reboot and shutdown commands don't work. I've seen this on a system with problems (which is why it needed rebooting).

You can trigger the "Magic SysRq" mechanism from the commandline:

```
echo b >/proc/sysrq-trigger
```

This is equivalent to alt-SysRq+b and will reboot the machine.

You may want to try "s" and "u" first to sync discs and unmount filesystems respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this page on computerhope.com](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000606.htm):

The command is **reboot**.  There is also **halt**, **poweroff** & **shutdown**.

Comment: halt & poweroff actually turn the machine off completely, shutdown will only reboot the machine with the correct switches provided.

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with any of the above, but you can also install gnome-do and enable the session management plugin, which lets you easily shutdown,reboot,suspend from gnome-do

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Virtual Environment It will put hard disk on Standby Mode: `sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now`.